# How to make DraggableScrollableSheet in proper order in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How to make DraggableScrollableSheet in proper order in Flutter web. When I scroll through the dates, there will be a Date, month, and year that will be skipped. For example April. When I scroll it will skip May and June and go straight to July. Same as Date and Year.

Code:

```
_readingDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    //_readingDateInMillisecond = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    _readingTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    _readingTimeIn24HourFormat =
        DateFormat('HH:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()).toString();


    void _showDatePickerBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          isScrollControlled: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          builder: (context) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                ),
                color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.001),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                    initialChildSize: 0.5,
                    minChildSize: 0.2,
                    maxChildSize: 1,
                    builder: (_, controller) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 200,
                          child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                            mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                            initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                            onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                              //_selectedReadingDate = newDateTime;
                              _readingDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')
                                  .format(newDateTime)
                                  .toString();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
```

How to solve this problem. I'm new to flutter and the DraggableScrollableSheet Widget is my first time using it. I think the problem is with initialChildSize, minChildSize and maxChildSize but when I change it still doesn't solve my problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

wrap `DraggableScrollableSheet` with `ScrollConfiguration`

```
ScrollConfiguration(
     behavior:ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
        dragDevices: {
             PointerDeviceKind.touch,
             PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
         }),
     child: DraggableScrollableSheet(),
),
```

Comment: this doesn't help with mouse scroll behavior.